# Can AWS Access Keys contain commas?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am building a prototype that uses AWS.  In my prototype, I pass around a list of items in a plain text string, and two of those items are AWS access keys.  I understand this will represent a security vulnerability, so I will be revisiting this approach, but it got me thinking....

What values can show up in the Access Key ID and the Secret Access Key?  I was delimiting the list with commas, but this would not work so well if my keys contained commas.  If they can contain commas, but they can't contain newlines, maybe I would just use newlines.

Comment: Not to point out the obvious, but you can delimit the list with whatever you want if you escape that character in the keys.  I'm pretty sure you can't count on anything being sacred in an AWS secret key.

Answer (score 10):

The Access Key ID is 20 alpha-numeric characters like 022QF06E7MXBSH9DHM02.

The Secret Access Key is 40 alpha-numeric-slash-plus characters like kWcrlUX5JEDGM/LtmEENI/aVmYvHNif5zB+d9+ct.

Source: http://alestic.com/2009/11/ec2-credentials

So...neither commas or newlines are going to be accepted in your keys.

Comment: Also, when creating access keys via the web console, they are available to download in a csv file, further indicating that neither access key ids or secret access keys contain commas.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whitepaper provided by AWS about security best practices. http://media.amazonwebservices.com/Whitepaper_Security_Best_Practices_2010.pdf

Also, if you need to get your security credentials onto an EC2 virtual machine, the most secure way of handling that is:

1. Use the IAM service to create a "user" with credentials that are restricted to *only* the tasks that you need the instance to be able to perform. (This will prevent stolen credentials from compromising your entire AWS account.)
2. Use EC2 "Instance Profiles", which will enable your EC2 instance to have your credentials provided to it via [instance metadata](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html).
3. If you can't use Instance Profiles for whatever reason, the next best thing is to [SCP](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Secure_copy) a file containing your credentials over to the instance. Since SCP leverages SSH, your credentials are ensured to be secured in-transit to the instance.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Correct, in fact I frown upon any AWS tools that do not use instance profiles. These are excellent in many ways, aside from the reasons you pointed out I've also found them very valuable when you need to setup multiple environments (production, qa, development). Not having the keys in your scripts really makes the scripts so much more portable.

Comment: While this may be good information on AWS security practices, it doesn't answer the question.